# hide titles based on page type?

Tags: 7

I want to disable titles from showing on main content pages, but have them show still on blog post/article pages.  I was using a CSS rule #page-title to hide them, and was thinking of working from that, but it doesn't work as well in dynamically generated pages. Comparing a post page to a main content page, I don't see any difference in the preceding css classes and ids.

How could I quickly change this behaviour?

I'm working on a self-built custom theme that doesn't have a lot of editing done to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the classes in the body tag, and I am sure you will find what you need to build the right CSS.

Hint: body.SomeClass #page-title { display:none; }

Comment: I tried that already. the class/id hierarchy is 100% identical between posts and pages

Comment: By posts do you mean a list of one or more articles? and a page is the full page with one article?

Comment: Do you have a URL or it's not publicly available ?

Comment: Normally you would have ex: node-type-article in the body, but not in a list of nodes

Comment: I was reading the inspector wrong.. there were differing body classes.

Comment: this may seem like nitpicking here but why would you build something simply to hide it? if there is no need for the title to exist, take it out of the code template.

Answer (score 2):

If these are different content types, you could create a separate node-*[type]*.tpl.php file for each, leaving out the title in one of them.

http://drupal.org/node/1089642

Answer (score 1):

under `node.tpl.php` remove the  element including the php if statement:

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

assuming you are using the blog module, under `node-[type].tpl.php` (which can be found via `$node->type`) simply keep the  element and php if statement.

FYI - this was the default node template from zen. yours may look different.

Answer (score 0):

Or just hide it:

```
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?> style="display:none"><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
```